# Get Image From Api And Display In Razor View

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have webApi method from which I have fetch the employee record and their hex encrypt image using Oracle database in a byte array, when I get the byte array in my application and call it in razor view using img src tag it is not displaying the image. 
Here is what I am trying so far:

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
    EmployeeRefVM emp = new EmployeeRefVM();
    emp.REF_NO = rdr["REF_NO"].ToString();
    emp.ENAME = rdr["ENAME"].ToString();
    emp.EMP_PIC = (byte[])rdr["EMP_PIC"];//get Image in byte[]
    emp.age = GetAge(emp.EMP_DOB);
    employeelist.Add(emp);
}
```

and in my .net core application I call it

```
TempData["EmpPic"] = employeeDetails.EMP_PIC;
public ActionResult Image()
{
    var allsystemconfig = _systemConfigServices.getAllSystemconfig();
    var wwwrootpath = _environment.WebRootPath;
    string filePAth = wwwrootpath + allsystemconfig.FirstOrDefault(q => q.MetaKey == "DefaultImage").MetaValue;
    byte[] imageData = (byte[])TempData["EmpPic"];
    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageData);
    return base.File(imageData, "image/png");
}
```

And here is my View

```
@{
    var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Model.EMP_PIC);
    var imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/jpeg;base64,{0}", base64);
    img src='@Url.Action("Image", "Party")' 
}
```

Image Save In Database:

[image]

Image Receive From DB:

[image]

Comment: This code is so mangled, I honestly have no idea what in the world you're doing or even attempting to do. You need to go back to the drawing board on this one.

Comment: Take a look at [Display image from byte array in ASP.NET MVC Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49865677/display-image-from-byte-array-in-asp-net-mvc-core/49916349).