# How to display an image from an API in Blazor .NET 7?

Tags: .net, image, bitmap, blazor, skiasharp

I have two microservices. One generates images and the second (Blazor) recieves this image. I want then to display that image WITHOUT saving it anywhere (I have bytes of that image and SKBitmap, because I use SkiaSharp).

Here is how I receive cards/images:

```
private async Task PostCard()
    {
        //Send data to CardGenerationService
        _cardState.Card = await _messageBusClient.SendCardToGenerate(Card);

        _navigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
    }
```

Here is how I would want to display them:

```
@if(_cardState.Card != null)
{
    <img src="@_cardState.Card"/>
}
```

But as you can guess, it dosen't work. I don't want to save the data anywhere (I want to simply display that card in my Blazor App, and that card is a kind of a png document).

Answer (score 2):

From [Display image from byte array in ASP.NET MVC Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49865677/display-image-from-byte-array-in-asp-net-mvc-core)

> Base64 encode the byte[] and use a Data URI:
>
> ```
> <img src="data:image/png;base64,[base64-encoded byte array here]">
> ```
>
> However, bear in mind two things.
>
> 1. Data URIs are supported in every modern browser, but notoriously do not work in IE 10 and under. That may not be an issue, but if you need to have legacy IE support, this is a non-starter.
> 2. Since you're Base64-encoding, the size of the "image" will balloon roughly 50%. As such, Data URIs are best used with small and simple images. If you've got large images or simply a lot of images, your HTML document can become a very large download. Since Data URIs are actually embedded in the HTML code, that means the browser cannot actually begin to render the page at all until the entire HTML document has loaded, which then also means that if it's megabytes in size, your users will be waiting a while.

Comment: And is there any way to display LARGE images? Preferably without saving it anywhere (or if we want to save it somewhere, without saving it directly on User's machine).
Like, for example, when you generate some documents on online generator - how to display them before User decides he wants to save it?